# Convert/export large number of attribute's information shapefiles to txt/csv format using python script?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm using the 2.8.1 Wien QGIS version.
I have a large number (more than 5000) of shapefiles that I want to convert to a csv or txt files to extract, to tables, the atributte information. The shapefiles are located in a directory and I want to keep the same name and directory for the new ones.

Does anyone know how to do this in a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered now how to do it.
I have shapefiles from everydays in specific month so I begin to define the dates that is going to appear in the new .cvs file, us:

```
Tprecip_20140601_FINAL.csv  #20140601 means year 2014, month June, day 1
```

I used this code and that's working now:

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import sys
import processing
import os
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

indir="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/FINAL"  #path's directory from shapefiles

########### inicial and final dates ########################
data1='20140601' #inicial date
data2='20140603' #final date

anoi = int(data1[:4])  #inicial year
mesi = int(data1[4:6]) #inicial month
diai = int(data1[6:8]) #inicial day
anof = int(data2[:4])  #final year
mesf = int(data2[4:6]) #final month
diaf = int(data2[6:8]) #final day

start_date = dt.datetime(anoi, mesi, diai)
end_date = dt.datetime(anof, mesf, diaf)

total_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1
##########################################################

for day in xrange(0, total_days):
        current_date = (start_date + dt.timedelta(days = day)).date()
        file_date = str(current_date.year)+"{0:02d}".format(current_date.month)+"{0:02d}".format(current_date.day)

        fullname="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/FINAL/TPrecip_"+file_date+"_FINAL.shp"
        str1="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/FINAL/TPrecip_"+file_date+"_FINAL.csv"
        processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat', fullname, 12, None, str1)
```